# Must a continuous function on an open interval, and having precisely one orbital point, contract?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

Let a periodic orbit of $f$ be a set of points $P$ such that $\forall p\in P:\exists n\in\Bbb N_{>0}:f^n(p)\in P$ where $f^n$ indicates composition.

> Must a continuous function on an open interval with no periodic orbits, other than a single fixed point (i.e. satisfying $f(p)=p$), necessarily contract to $p$ on iteration?

Let $f:(l,r)\to(l,r)$ be a continuous function on an open interval of $\Bbb R$, having precisely one fixed point $p$ satisfying $l<p<r$.

Then we need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)=p$ or prove otherwise.

contract on iteration to $p$ as its limit?

For what types of $f$ will it converge in finitely many iterations for all $x\in(l,r)$?

---

I'm aware of Sharkovskii's theorem which is related but doesn't seem to help.  I think something much more elementary is needed.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ on $]-1,1[$. -- Or any S-shaped graph intersecting the diagonal three times on the open interval between the outer intersection points

Comment: Could you state in question your definition of "contract to $p$ on iteration"? In particular does each iteration need to be strictly less, or even more less than a constant <1 closer?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank-you. Is there a counterexample in $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @user334732 Of course. Let $f(x)=\min\{\frac12x+\frac12,\max\{\frac12x-\frac12,2x\}\}$ on$]-1,1[$

Comment: @user334732 The outer two intersections are supposed to be the boundary points of our open interval, hence are not fixpoints